# How to speed up my lapply iterating over a list searching for values in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, filter, lapply

I have the following code, and I run it many times since it's inside my multiple models with different parameters, this special code is the most time consuming one, is there a faster way to make it?

```
membership_labels = unlist(lapply(comun$membership, 
                                    function(x) membership_table[
                                      membership_table$membership == x,]$membership_label))
```

Describing the data:

- `comun$membership`:

```
c(4, 6, 9, 6, 7, 7, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 6, 
3, 7, 7, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 3, 5, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
8, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 9, 7, 9, 3, 19, 8, 6, 9, 8, 6, 19, 2, 2, 3, 2, 19, 7, 3, 
3, 7, 7, 2, 9, 3, 3, 19, 2, 3, 7, 11, 3, 17, 7, 9, 3, 9, 6, 7, 
6, 3, 17, 8, 3, 3, 19, 3, 3, 6, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 6, 3, 9, 6, 6, 
6, 7, 8, 4, 6, 6, 3, 7, 6, 6, 8, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 18, 6, 3, 3, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 3, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 8, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 9, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7, 8, 3, 3, 17, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 
17, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 2, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 12, 12, 8, 2, 6, 7, 6, 
6, 7, 3, 6, 12, 6, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 7, 7, 1, 16, 
7, 7, 6, 12, 7, 7, 2, 6, 6, 7, 3, 3, 6, 8, 9, 9, 6, 3, 6, 6, 
6, 18, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 17, 6, 8, 6, 6, 8, 10, 3, 14, 16, 6, 1, 
7, 16, 7, 5, 1, 11, 1, 19, 7, 3, 2, 7, 5, 8, 7, 14, 2, 17, 7, 
7, 11, 7, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 16, 6, 1, 7, 6, 7, 14, 2, 7, 2, 10, 
7, 7, 1, 2, 7, 7, 7, 5, 1, 7, 9, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 5, 13, 1, 9, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 9, 9, 6, 6, 3, 6, 18, 15, 7, 
12, 7, 6, 7, 6, 17, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8, 18, 6, 
8, 6, 6, 6, 12, 12, 6, 11, 2, 12, 8, 8, 8, 6, 3, 7, 3, 1, 1, 
8, 7, 6, 9, 6, 18, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 2, 18, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 1, 
14, 6, 6, 9, 9, 7, 3, 6, 6, 9, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 6, 3, 9, 9, 
3, 7, 3, 6, 6, 9, 6, 6, 3, 9, 6, 9, 11, 11, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 10, 
7, 9, 13, 10, 10, 2, 1, 5, 1, 16, 10, 10, 5, 10, 7, 10, 10, 5, 
10, 10, 1, 7, 5, 10, 1, 2, 2, 10, 10, 1, 1, 14, 16, 7, 1, 1, 
1, 7, 7, 16, 1, 5, 6, 1, 9, 1, 6, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 18, 18, 16, 
1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 10, 9, 1, 10, 
1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 9, 6, 7, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 
1, 9, 10, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 16, 12, 6, 2, 5, 1, 12, 
1, 6, 1, 12, 5, 1, 5, 12, 7, 5, 2, 10, 2, 1, 7, 1, 1, 5, 9, 10, 
5, 10, 10, 1, 5, 10, 1, 9, 2, 1, 6, 10, 1, 6, 1, 12, 9, 1, 3, 
6, 13, 9, 5, 1, 15, 7, 2, 12, 1, 12, 6, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 
7, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1, 18, 8, 6, 1, 14, 1, 1, 
16, 15, 8, 1, 12, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 13, 2, 14, 16, 17, 4, 2, 4, 
4, 4, 2, 13, 2, 13, 16, 4, 10, 1, 2, 10, 13, 13, 14, 7, 2, 7, 
10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 1, 10, 5, 10, 7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 5, 11, 7, 7, 
7, 10, 5, 10, 10, 4, 10, 4, 10, 6, 10, 5, 10, 5, 19, 1, 19, 2, 
10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 5, 14, 10, 6, 10, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
19, 17, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 7, 9, 6, 9, 5, 8, 6, 2, 1, 1, 9, 
1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 14, 7, 18, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 6, 3, 15, 
1, 10, 6, 2, 6, 10, 15, 2, 12, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 11, 6, 1, 2, 18, 
15, 5, 8, 5, 9, 1, 13, 3, 8, 11, 8, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 3, 8, 2, 1, 
15, 1, 15, 2, 9, 9, 9, 6, 13, 2, 10, 11, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 10, 4, 10, 4, 13, 4, 4, 4, 2, 14, 13, 10, 
5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 2, 6, 1, 11, 1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 15, 5, 1, 
5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 4, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 4, 10, 
5, 10, 11, 10, 2, 10, 5, 10, 5, 4, 5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 10, 5, 5, 
10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 10, 1, 1, 5, 
1, 10, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 10, 11, 5, 1, 6, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 
10, 5, 10, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 15, 2, 4, 4, 4, 10, 10, 4, 10, 10, 
4, 4, 10, 6, 4, 4, 4, 10, 4, 10, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 8, 10, 4, 10, 
14, 6, 2, 6, 10, 9, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 8, 6, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 1, 11, 1, 5, 15, 5, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 1, 10, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
4, 10, 2, 10, 4, 4, 19, 15, 10, 4, 13, 2, 17, 4, 17, 4, 4, 4, 
2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 16, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 15, 4, 4, 5, 11, 10, 2, 2, 2, 14, 2, 18, 
5, 2, 8, 4, 10, 10, 4, 5, 4, 2, 10, 10, 11, 2, 15, 10, 11, 1, 
4, 4, 14, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 14, 8, 8, 8, 4, 2, 4, 1, 11, 1, 4, 
2, 2, 6, 2, 6, 9, 1, 6, 2, 8, 6, 2, 2, 2, 6, 9, 2, 4, 2, 2, 14, 
6, 9, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 15, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 8, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 17, 2, 
2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 
10, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 9, 2, 9, 4, 11, 4, 2, 15, 2, 
4, 10, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 6, 4, 4, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2, 1, 4, 
2, 8, 2, 8, 4, 10, 4, 4, 4, 5, 10, 4, 10, 4)
```

- `membership_table`:

```
   membership community_count community_maj_count membership_label
        <int>           <int>               <int>            <int>
 1          1             276                 171                2
 2          2             319                 206                2
 3          3             482                 322               -2
 4          4             404                 293                2
 5          5             161                  88                2
 6          6             271                 110               -2
 7          7             332                 167               -2
 8          8              56                  46                2
 9          9              77                  37                2
10         10             434                 244                2
11         11              27                  12               -2
12         12              24                  11                2
13         13              19                   8                2
14         14              17                   8               -2
15         15              18                  16                2
16         16              14                   5               -2
17         17              13                   8               -2
18         18              16                  13                2
19         19              12                   9               -2
```

with `dput`:

```
structure(list(membership = 1:19, community_count = c(276L, 319L, 
482L, 404L, 161L, 271L, 332L, 56L, 77L, 434L, 27L, 24L, 19L, 
17L, 18L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 12L), community_maj_count = c(171L, 
206L, 322L, 293L, 88L, 110L, 167L, 46L, 37L, 244L, 12L, 11L, 
8L, 8L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 9L), membership_label = c(2L, 2L, -2L, 
2L, 2L, -2L, -2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, -2L, 2L, 2L, -2L, 2L, -2L, -2L, 
2L, -2L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

It's important to notice that membership in `membership_table` is sequential starting at 1, but not always, it can start at any index and have gaps between.

Temporary answer:

```r
membership_index_list <- list()
membership_index_list[membership_table$membership] = membership_table$membership_label
membership_labels <- membership_index_list[comun$membership]
```

Comment: `membership_table$membership_label[membership_table$membership %in% comun$membership]`?

Comment: Code golf: `with(membership_table, membership_label[membership %in% comun$membership])`

Comment: @r2evans I need the `membership_label` for each value in `comun$membership`, which have a different length. Both codes you wrote returns `membership$label` if it's inside `comun$membership`

Comment: Your code: for each of `comun$membership`, it looks for matching `membership` and returns the corresponding `membership_label`. All of this is returned in a list due to `lapply`. Then you `unlist` it, so the result is a vector. I don't see how it is different.

Comment: @r2evans I think the OP original method will return duplicate `membership$label` in order according to each `comun$membership`. ie, labels for each `comun$membership` collapsed into a vector so `length(membership_labels )` can be greater than length of table.

Comment: My approach will return duplicate labels as well, depending on the data. Without sample data, though, I'm done with conjecture. Felipe, sample data please?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @r2evans I've add the original data

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you, I didn't know `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change my comment to use `match` instead of `%in%`:

```r
membership_table$membership_label[match(comun$membership, membership_table$membership)]
#    [1]  2 -2  2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2
#   [40] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2
#   [79] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  2 -2 -2 -2 -2  2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  2 -2  2 -2 -2  2 -2  2  2 -2 -2
### ...truncated...
# [1366]  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -2  2  2  2  2 -2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 -2  2  2  2  2
# [1405]  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Depending on your use and confidence in the data completeness, you might see `NA` when there is something within `comun$membership` that is not found in `membership_table`. For instance,

```r
membership_table$membership_label[match(c(99, head(comun$membership)), membership_table$membership)]
# [1] NA  2 -2  2 -2 -2 -2
```

where `99` is not among the available `$membership` values.